# How to use onTouchEvent in Arraylist of bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, arraylist, drag, touch-event

I create a class 'Element' to get bitmap.And ...

```
ArrayList<Element> mElements = new ArrayList<Element>();
```

...
In surfaceview to draw

```
synchronized (mElements) {
            for (Element element : mElements) {
                element.doDraw(canvas);
            }
        }
```

Now,I want to set onTouchEvent to Multiple bitmap move or drag.
Maybe another Method is better to Dynamic add bitmap and move them.
please help , thanks